# Groovy Grails Tools Suit (GGTS) Maven plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, grails, groovy

What is the fastest way to install maven integration plugin in GGTS 3.4.0?

I see that the plugin is not installed by default in GGTS 3.4.0.
When I search the Marketplace for `"m2e"` I get whole lot of different plugins, most of which do not apply, e.g. "Maven Integration for Juno".

Comment: did you ask a question to answer it just seconds later?

Comment: I don't recall, but I am sure that I wanted to answer it for everyone who had/has this question. Not sure why you are asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to Help->Install new software.
2. Press "Add" button and paste "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" into "location" field.
3. Install the plugin.